# onLocationChanged is not call continuously?

Tags: android, location, google-play-services

I wrote some code to get a continuously track location it works but the update triggers only sometimes after restarting the app after the screen timeout, but not allways...

In the "Google Play Services", i use only com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.3.0 (to reduce the size).

The AndroidManifest.xml is set for an ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" permission.
The  GPS and "Wi-Fi & mobile network location" of my device is on.

Thanks in advance for help.
Here is the main part:

```
import android.location.Location;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import  comm.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks;
import  com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
    ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {

private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;

private final static int CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9000;

protected TextView txtlat, txtlong;

// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Create
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    txtlat = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtlat);
    txtlong = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtlong);

    if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
    }

    createLocationRequest();
}

protected void createLocationRequest() {
    mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(10000); // 10sec
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(5000); // 5sec
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
}

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

// ---------------------------------------------------------------------
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }
}

// ---------------------------------------------------------------------
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
    Location location=LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
    if (location == null) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
    } else {
        displayLocation(location);
    }
}

// ---------------------------------------------------------------------
public void onLocationChanged (Location location) {
    displayLocation(location);
}

// ---------------------------------------------------------------------
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Try `mLocationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(0.1F);` but only do that for testing.

Comment: I think you have to put `@Override` annotation on the `onLocationChanged` method, it is for the compiler to make sure you are overrriding a method. I'm not sure if it is just your copy-paste but this import `import  comm.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks;` is not correct, it should be `import  com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks;`

Comment: Ok,thanks, i will correct. I find something, in the onConnected method, if getLastLocation return an object displayLocation is called  without activate the requestLocationUpdates. I think this is the problem. Finally i don't need the getLastLocation, the requestLocationUpdates is enough. Thank's for your answers.